# Retrieving data from Dictionary C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, arraylist

So i am currently creating a program that maps a String key and a ArrayList of objects (currently integers)

Now i have created a class called `Operator` that has a method which returns a Dictionary.

To test the output of my Dictionary i decided to make pop (`Messagebox`) that displays the integer value.

However this proved to be a deal breaker for me. After abit of research i managed to assemble the following code:

```
          Operator op = new Operator();
        ArrayList a;
        op.startCollecting().TryGetValue("Henvendelser", out a);
        int value = (int) a[0];
        MessageBox.Show("" + value);
```

*Note the startCollecting method returns the Dictionary*

When trying to get the data i first have to create a new empty ArrayList, clone my existing ArrayList into that ArrayList, create an integer value, pull the item from the ArrayList at index 0 and then show the messagebox.

I am originally a java programmer, and in Java i would have been able to do this:

```
int value = op.startCollecting().get("Henvendelser").get(0);
```

Am i doing it wrong in C#? is there an easier way of Retrieving data?

Comment: `Arraylist`... Do you absolutely *have* to use that? Since .Net 2.0 there is the much better [List<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/6sh2ey19.aspx). In your case `List<int>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve your value like this :

```
var value = op.startCollection()["Henvendelser"];
```

Comment: That returns an arrayList of integer values Edit. You were actually correct however the following is needed in order to be complete: 

  int value = (int) op.startCollecting()["Henvendelser"][0];

Comment: `op.startCollection()["Henvendelser"][0]`?

Answer (score 2):

First things first: You should use generic [lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/6sh2ey19.aspx) instead of ArrayList in c#.

To your question:

```
    Dictonary<string, List<int>> dictonary = op.startCollecting();
    if(dictonary.ContainsKey("Henvendelser"))
    {
        List<int> list = dictonary["Henvendelser"];
        int value = list[0];
        MessageBox.Show(value.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `StartCollecting` method roughly looks like this...

```
class Operator
{
    public IDictionary<string, IList<int>> StartCollecting() 
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

... you can use the indexers of `IDictionary` and `IList` to retrieve your value:

```
op.StartCollecting()["Henvendelser"][0]
```

Comment: I see alot of people using the Interface i know its not part of my question but can you explain this ? as stated i am usually a Java programmer and C# is fairly new to me

Comment: Well, programming to interfaces is nothing C# specific, its just good practice to hide your implementation details from consumers.

Comment: In case your question refers to generics: By using generic collections you do not have to cast the contents of your collections to the expected type. Of course this only makes sense if you know in advance what items will be in the list and that all items have a common super type.